# Cannot get data-id in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a newbie. I created my first nodejs project with mongodb. And i get some errors.
Actually, "data-id" attribute cannot get id string in database.  There is my index.pug.

```
        if (data.length)
      each item in data
        tr
          td #{item['_id']}
          td #{item['name']}
          td #{item['email']}
          td
            a.btn.btn-primary.editlink(href='javascript:void(0)', data-id = '#{item["_id"]}') Edit
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;
            a.btn.btn-danger(href='/delete?id=#{item["_id"]}', onclick='return confirm("Are you sure ?")') Delete

script.
  $(function() { 
    $('.editlink').on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/fetchdata",
        data: { id: id },
      }).done(function( data ) {
        $('#id').val(data[0]['_id']);
        $('#name').val(data[0]['name']);
        $('#email').val(data[0]['email']);            
        $("#subbtn").val('Edit');
        $('#form1').attr('action', '/edit');
      });
    });
  });
```

My index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, client) {
  if(err) {  console.log(err); throw err;  }
  data = '';
  var db = client.db(dbname);
  db.collection('products').find().toArray(function(err, docs){
  if(err) throw err;
  res.render('index', {data: docs});
  console.log(docs);      
  client.close();
   });
 });
});
router.get('/fetchdata', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.query.id;
  MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, client) {
  if(err) {  console.log(err); throw err;  }
  data = '';
  var db = client.db(dbname);        
  db.collection('products').find({_id: new     mongodb.ObjectId(id)}).toArray(function(err, docs){
  if(err) throw err;
  res.send(docs);
  client.close();
  });
});
});
```

I updated my script with $(document).ready(function(){} ) but it doesn't work .

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to initially render the template from your node server? It is also a good idea to add a `$(document).ready(function(){` wrapper to your script before setting a click listener.

Comment: Thank you but i'm still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may be the problem is in `Edit` part

you have to set `data-id= item['_id']`

as

```
 td
            a.btn.btn-primary.editlink(href='javascript:void(0)', data-id = item["_id"]) Edit
            | &nbsp;&nbsp;
            a.btn.btn-danger(href='/delete?id='+#{item["_id"]}, onclick='return confirm("Are you sure ?")') Delete
```

Comment: Can you help me again with delete?id item?

Comment: Thank you  again !